# UniqueID for timestamps with certain conditions

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Spark dataframe composed of this two columns I want to give an ID to each row based on a simple condition on the timestamp column.
For each User if the difference between the next and the previous timestamp is less than 10 seconds I keep appending the same ID, else I update the ID and keep going until I have assigned an ID to each row.
Everything should be coded in python since I'm using PySpark.
To make things easier to understand here's an example:

Starting DF

```
    +------------------+
    |   User| timestamp|
    +------------------+
    |  user0|     100  |
    |  user1|     102  |
    |  user0|     109  |
    |  user2|     103  |
    |  user1|     108  |
    |  user0|     119  |
    |  user0|     140  |
    |  user0|     142  |
    +------------------+
```

Desired DF is something like this

```
    +----------------------+
    |   User| timestamp| ID|
    +----------------------+
    |  user0|     100  |  1|
    |  user1|     102  |  2|
    |  user0|     109  |  1|
    |  user2|     103  |  3|
    |  user1|     108  |  2|
    |  user0|     119  |  1|
    |  user0|     140  |  4|
    |  user0|     142  |  4|
    +----------------------+
```

or maybe something like this if the algorithm assigns before the ID for a given user. I don't really care, either is fine.

```
    +----------------------+
    |   User| timestamp| ID|
    +----------------------+
    |  user0|     100  |  1|
    |  user1|     102  |  3|
    |  user0|     109  |  1|
    |  user2|     103  |  4|
    |  user1|     108  |  3|
    |  user0|     119  |  1|
    |  user0|     140  |  2|
    |  user0|     142  |  2|
    +----------------------+
```

As you can see user0 with timestamp 140 has a different ID (2) because the difference with the previous timestamp is greater than 10.

This would be easy enough if I could loop and assign each cell dynamically, but it defeats the purpose of using spark dataframes and also I think it can't be done since they are immutable.

What is the most efficient way to do this in Spark?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate an ID for each user first, and then combine them across different users as below.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

w = Window.partitionBy('User').orderBy('timestamp')

df2 = df.withColumn(
    'begin',
    F.coalesce(
        F.col('timestamp') - F.lag('timestamp').over(w) > 10, 
        F.lit(True)
    ).cast('int')
).withColumn(
    'userid',
    F.sum('begin').over(w.rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, 0))
).withColumn(
    'ID',
    F.dense_rank().over(Window.orderBy('userid', 'User'))
)

# If you just want to keep your columns, do:
# df2 = df2.select('User', 'timestamp', 'ID')

df2.show()
+-----+---------+-----+------+---+
| User|timestamp|begin|userid| ID|
+-----+---------+-----+------+---+
|user0|      100|    1|     1|  1|
|user0|      109|    0|     1|  1|
|user0|      119|    0|     1|  1|
|user1|      102|    1|     1|  2|
|user1|      108|    0|     1|  2|
|user2|      103|    1|     1|  3|
|user0|      140|    1|     2|  4|
|user0|      142|    0|     2|  4|
+-----+---------+-----+------+---+
```

Comment: First and foremost thank you very much for the quick answer, i'm trying to understand the code as i'm new to spark and this is extremely helpful.
the `w` variable where is initializated? i suppose it's a window object? but what should it be?

Comment: @nonoDa sorry I forgot to include that part of the code - see edited answer

Comment: Hi i was wondering if you have any idea why if i load a parquet using `spark.read.load(filepath)`  after i use the code you've given me to merge the timestamps it takes a lot of time to do any action, such as a simple `count()`.   However `count()` is really fast if i do it right after i load the parquet. I guess it has something to do with maybe `paritionBy()` in the code provided in the answer and maybe `coalesce()`. i've tried both `repartition(1)` and `coalesce(1)` but it still takes a lot of time

Comment: If you want faster performance, you can call `df.cache()` to cache the dataframe, so that the computation will be run once only.

Comment: no need for changing partitions. Coalescing to one partition will only make it slower.

Comment: but how come if i call `count()` right after `spark.read.load(filepath)` it takes a few ms, however if merge the timestamps (therefore reducing the number of rows of the df) if i call then again  `count()` it takes minutes? is it becouse of this line F.coalesce(F.col('timestamp') - F.lag('timestamp').over(w) > 10,F.lit(True) ? is doing `df.cache()` the only thing i can do? thanks in advance!

Comment: The computation of the ids takes time, and due to lazy evaluation, that computation is delayed until you call `count`. So you experience a long run time when calling `count`.